# How to remove arrow from the spinner when i click On spinner?

Tags: android, spinner, android-selector

I tried this below code its showing normal effects.I want when i click on `spinner` the down should hide..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape>
                    <gradient android:angle="90" android:endColor="#B3BBCC" android:startColor="#E8EBEF" android:type="linear" />

                    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" />

                    <corners android:radius="4dp" />

                    <padding android:bottom="3dp" android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="3dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <bitmap android:gravity="bottom|right" android:src="@drawable/spinner_arrow" />
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>    
</selector>
```

Thank is Advance...

Comment: Just use a transparent icon in selector .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made my custom spinner like this follow these step:

Step 1: create one Drawable resource file inside your drawable folder say spinnerbg.xml and write below code in your xml file.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>
            <layer-list>
                <item>
                    <shape>
                        <gradient android:angle="90"
                            android:endColor="@color/spinner"
                            android:startColor="@color/spinner"
                            android:type="linear" />

                        <corners android:radius="0dp" />

                        </shape>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <bitmap android:gravity="bottom|right"
                        android:src="@drawable/dropdown" />

                </item>
            </layer-list>
        </item>

    </selector>
```

Step:2 Inside your style.xml write below code

```
 <style name="spinner_style" >
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinnerbg</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">5dp</item>
    </style>
```

step:3 And finallay inside your spinner use style like this.

```
                 <Spinner   
                    style="@style/spinner_style"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                </Spinner>
```